# Does OpenEBS support shared storage?

Tags: storage, kubernetes

Does OpenEBS provide any kind of storage class that enables shared storage among containers? let's say I have 5 containers that need to access the exact same data. I have several containers doing AI training that need access to a shared image database, so it be like ReadWrite Many way.

Answer (score 0):

OpenEBS operates on block level, hence can't be used as shared storage.
I can suggest you to have a look at some other storage solutions, for example NFS based.